# Is there a way to hide the line numbers in Ace Editor?

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

Is there any way to remove the line numbers when using the ace editor?

Similar to removing the print margin as shown below?

```
editor.setShowPrintMargin(false);
```

Comment: @epascarello perfect thxs. Wanna add as an answer so i can accept it?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use

`editor.renderer.setShowGutter(true/false);`

http://ace.c9.io/#VirtualRenderer.setShowGutter=&nav=api&api=virtual_renderer

Editor Options
https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/wiki/Configuring-Ace

Answer (score 27):

If you want to hide the line numbers but keep the gutter for the folding widgets:

```
editor.renderer.setOption('showLineNumbers', false);
```

Comment: It is now:
`editor.setOption('showLineNumbers', false);`

Answer (score 10):

Updating the answer for version 1.4.7. You can set multiple options for ace editor like this, including `showGutter`

```
this.editor.getEditor().setOptions({
    enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
    enableSnippets: true,
    enableLiveAutocompletion: true,
    showGutter: false,
    maxLines: 20
  });
```

Comment: Wonderful answer. Thank you